# How create edit a form that is displaying statuses in a check box based on a field in table of a mysql database?

Tags: php

The right status is not being returned in my checkbox which is a tick for 1 and blank when status is 0.

```
<input type='checkbox' value='$row['pls_pay']' name='pls_pay' if ($row['pls_pay'] == '1'){checked='checked'} />
```

I am getting to following error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\msa\tobepayed.php on line 79

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

NB. The form is within an echo.

Comment: You should post more of your code as this mix of html and php does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is inside of an echo statement, you could do the following:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$row['pls_pay']."' name='pls_pay'"; if ($row['pls_pay'] == '1'){ echo "checked='checked'"; } echo "/>";
```

Without more context or a bigger chunk of you're code, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax mixes the html and the php... It's normal ?

Otherwise, test this

```
<input type='checkbox' value='$row['pls_pay']' name='pls_pay' if ($row['pls_pay'] == '1'){$checked='checked'} />
```

or this

```
<input type='checkbox' value='<?php echo $row['pls_pay'] ; ?>' name='pls_pay' <?php if ($row['pls_pay'] == '1'){ echo 'checked' ;}?> />
```